# Is it possible to run Linux apps on Chromium OS?

Tags: chromium-os

Chromium OS/Chrome OS is based on the GNU/Linux kernel and is considered by some to be an odd sort of Linux distribution. I know through Crouton you can run other distributions inside the OS. However, is it somehow possible to directly run, or build binaries for Chromium, and if so, how would this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an easy way to install linux on even older chromebooks and other devices that run either the chrome os or chromium os.

this is what i did:

1. install crustini (crouton) app from the web store app on the chromebook.
2. click on the wiki link in the crustini apps help page.
3. follow instructions in the wiki for sure fire no-fail linux installs!
   good luck!